# How do I add numbers to specific items in a nested list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested

So I'm working on a school project themed on Christmas and am a bit stuck.
From the brief, the program is meant to deliver presents to children and so I am trying to remove one present at a time from this list:

```
Presents = [["Toys",10],["Games",5],["Sweets",15]]
```

However, I have yet to find a way to do this as I can't seem to be able to minus one singular number from one section of this nested list.

In simple is it possible from this list:

```
Presents = [["Toys",10],["Games",5],["Sweets",15]]
```

to, for example, just remove one toy and then end up with the list as

```
Presents = [["Toys",9],["Games",5],["Sweets",15]]
```

instead of having toys as 10.

If so please can someone help me as this is due very soon

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are using the wrong dataformat. Why not use a dictionary instead? Or better still, use a [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a dictionary specialising in amounts per key. `Presents['Toys'] -= 1` is then trivial.

Comment: I haven't really played about with dictionaries and especially not counter() but I will definitely try that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `collections.OrderedDict` here. You can convert this to dict as:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict   # To also maintain order of original list

>>> Presents = [["Toys",10],["Games",5],["Sweets",15]]
>>> my_dict = OrderedDict(Presents)
>>> my_dict
OrderedDict([('Toys', 10), ('Games', 5), ('Sweets', 15)])
```

Then, to decrease the value of `"Toys"` key, do:

```
>>> my_dict['Toys'] -= 1
>>> my_dict['Toys']
9
```

For converting it back to `list` of `tuples`, call `dict.items()` as:

```
>>> list(my_dict.items())
[('Toys', 9), ('Games', 5), ('Sweets', 15)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this out now.